# How to use Ajax call completed (done) in this case

Tags: jquery

On load of a Page , I am doing a AJAX call as shown

```
<script>
$(function() {

    var ajaxQuery = fecthDocumentData("","");

    ajaxQuery.done(function() {

    });
});
</script>


function fecthDocumentData(document_id, btnname)
{
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url + '/OMS/admin/document?document_row=' + document_id + '&btnName=' + btnname,
        jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonp: false,
        success: function(response) {
         var res = response;

    },
        error: function(e) {}
    });


}
```

My question is how can i know that the Ajax call has been completed in this case ??

I tried to use

```
ajaxQuery.done(function() {

alert('Ajax call completed callback called ');

});
```

But i am getting error as **cannot read property of undefined at this line**  `ajaxQuery.done(function() {`

Comment: after completion,success or error will occur

Comment: but both are two different functions and the success result will call another ajax call , so they might get mixed up .

Answer (score 3):

Return the promise of the `$.ajax()` call

```
function fecthDocumentData(document_id, btnname) {
    return $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url + '/OMS/admin/document?document_row=' + document_id + '&btnName=' + btnname,
        jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonp: false,
        success: function(response) {
            var res = response;
        },
        error: function(e) {}
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the response in success function ... try to alert 0r console the response data..

ie,

```
function fecthDocumentData(document_id, btnname)
{
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url + '/OMS/admin/document?document_row=' + document_id + '&btnName=' + btnname,
        jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonp: false,
        success: function(response) {
         var res = response;
         alert(res); //check out the value and if you get any value here .. and to what ever stuff you want here 


    },
        error: function(e) {}
    });


}
```

there is no necessary to use .done function...

```
ajaxQuery.done(function() {

    });
```

you can do it inside the success function only